# Is that possible to write this weekly crontab expression?

Tags: cron

i need to write a cron expression but i really dont know how neither whether is possible to write it

```
from 5 to five weeks once at 0am at tuesday
```

so running today only executes 5 weeks from now..

does anybody knows?

Comment: i think this is not possible.. i have found this to help making crontab expressions http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 0):

Run command once after 5 weeks? Cron is not very handy for this, try "at" instead.

```
at 00:00 + 5 weeks
at> /home/user/command
at> ^D
```